# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class LoginServlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat7

I am getting the following error.

```
    type Exception report

    message Error instantiating servlet class LoginServlet

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class LoginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    root cause

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 logs.
```

I am using annotation instead of web.xml file. Since all answers are provided for projects with web.xml file. I find difficult to locate answer for my problem. Given below are my login.jsp page and LoginServlet class codes.

login.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>APIS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
    <%@page import= "com.servlet.LoginServlet" %>

    </head>
    <body>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                <li  class="active"><a href="login.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</a></li>
                <%

                                        if (session.getAttribute("agencyname") != null) {

                                            if (session.getAttribute("agencyname").toString().equals("slc")) {
                                    %>
                                <li><a href="register.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;New Register</a></li>

                                <%
                                    }


                                %>
                                <li><a href="resetPassword.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reset Password</a></li>
                                <%
                                        }

                                %>

              </ul>


              <form class="login-form" action="LoginServlet" method="post">
              <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:30px;">Sign In</h2>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="UserName" name="UserName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Submit">
         </form>

    </body>

    <script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </html>
```

LoginServlet class

```
    package com.servlet;

    import com.controller.UserDAO;
    import com.model.OgaUser;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


    @WebServlet(name = "LoginServlet", urlPatterns = {"/LoginServlet"})
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet LoginServlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet LoginServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);


}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    System.out.println("******************************");
    System.out.println("In doPost method");

    String username = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String password = request.getParameter("Password");
    //OgaUser ou = new OgaUser();

    String loginResult = UserDAO.login(username, password);
    if (loginResult != null) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (loginResult.equalsIgnoreCase("slc")) {
            session.setAttribute("agency", "slc");
            session.setAttribute("username","Harsha");
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    } else {

    }

}


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    }
```

Comment: Can you check for missing dependencies? 

Also try out mentioning serialVersion like mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/q/29883080/200063

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;

or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921540/http-status-500-error-instantiating-servlet-class-pkg-coreservlet 

Also, what is level of JavaEE container you are using? Does it support annotation?

Comment: on a side note: you are calling `processRequest`  from `doPost` , which looks like irrelevant.

Comment: root cause is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginServlet` , so there may be some issues in folder structure , could you post your folder structure ?

Comment: @JAVY  Given below is my folder structure  <login.jsp location>"/home/swuser/NetBeansProjects/FileUpload/EJBFileUpload/web"  <LoginServlet class location>"/home/swuser/NetBeansProjects/FileUpload/EJBFileUpload/src/java/com/servlet"  Please support. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a ClassNotFoundException issue. "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginServlet" . Make sure you have placed the jar file containing LoginServlet in the class-path which is normally WEB-INF/classes and/or WEB-INF/lib